# PHP mysql sorting the row with using ORDER BY DESC

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am creating a game using UNITY it was PHP bla bla...
Thou i have some little things that i need to figure out to sort the row.
The thing is --it is a game that i need to sort the players.
for example if the player 3 leaves/left the game then the player 3 have the uid 2

then we only have player 1 player 2 and player 4 they have 0 1 3

```
player1 = 0
player2 = 1
player3 = 2
player4 = 3
```

so what i need to do is that sort that out so if `player3 left uid 2`
i need to do sorting
it will go this way

```
player4 = 3
player2 = 1
player1 = 0
```

i used the `sort( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql ) )` but i only got error
i used also the `sort( $row['players'] );`
`$row['players']` this was the `0 1 2 3`
but its not sorting the thing that i need well it sort but the output of that is this

```
player1 = 3
player2 = 1
player4 = 0
```

which is wrong its not equal now for the players and the current player

help me guys what should be the right code

I hope everyone understand what i need to solve here.

I also try to used the ORDER BY players DESC but its not good. I know there is something more specify ordering for that.

I have some more explaination this is the order/sorting that i need to solve.

```
GameID   Turn   
3         2
6         1
7         2
5         2
8         0
9         1

return should be { for example GameID 6 is TURN for the Game or Left in the Game }
GameID   Turn
6         1
9         1
8         0
3         2
5         2
7         2

another example { for example GameID 7 is TURN for the Game or Left in the Game }
GameID   Turn
7         2
3         2
5         2
8         0
9         1
6         1
```

Here are my Query

```
$email_val = email@sample.com';

if( $email_val != null ){
    $sqlCheckError = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM game WHERE player1 = '".$email_val."' || player2 = '".$email_val."' || player3 = '".$email_val."' || player4 = '".$email_val."' " ) or die ( mysql_error() );
    $gameCheck = mysql_fetch_array($sqlCheckError);
    // CHECK FOR GAMEID ERROR
    $gameIDCheck = $gameCheck['gameID'];
    // EMAIL EQUAL TO THE CURRENTTURN WHERE ID
    $sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM game WHERE player1 = '" . $email_val . "' || player2 = '".$email_val."' || player3 = '".$email_val."' || player4 = '".$email_val."' " ) or die ( mysql_error() );
    // FIXED THE SORT OF 
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql ) ) {                
        $p1 = $row['player1'];
        $p2 = $row['player2'];
        $p3 = $row['player3'];
        $p4 = $row['player4'];

        if ($asterisk > 0) {
            echo "*";
        }
        echo $row['gameID'] . '|';
        echo $row['gameStatus'] . '|';

        echo $getNameLower->_NAME_LOWER_PLAYER_ONE_( $p1 );
        echo $getNameLower->_NAME_LOWER_PLAYER_TWO_( $p2 );

        if ( !empty( $p3 ) ){
            echo $getNameLower->_NAME_LOWER_PLAYER_THR_( $p3 );
        } else {
            echo '';
        }
        if ( !empty( $p4) ){
            echo $getNameLower->_NAME_LOWER_PLAYER_FOU_( $p4 );
        } else {
            echo '';
        }

        echo '|' . $row['start'];
        echo '|' . $row['currentTurn'];
        echo '|' . $row['lastWord'];
        echo '|' . $row['lastPlayer'];
        echo '|' . $row['lastPoints'];

        $cur = $row['currentTurn'];
        // CHECK THE CurrentTurn then PUT IT AS PICURL
        if ( $cur == '0' ) { echo $getPIC->purl_1( $p1 ); } 
        elseif( $cur == '1' ) { echo $getPIC->purl_2( $p2 ); }
        elseif( $cur == '2' ) { echo $getPIC->purl_3( $p3 ); }
        elseif( $cur == '3' ) { echo $getPIC->purl_4( $p4 ); }

        $asterisk++;
    }

    if( $gameIDCheck == null ){
        echo '0';           
    }
}
else{
    echo '0';
}
```

Yes i already think that in a first place also. Order By is really easy to sort everything. But it will not sort something like this 2 0 1 and `1 2 0` thus, if we use ORDER BY DESC 2 1 0 and ASC 0 1 2 i hope its clear now

Comment: What was the problem with `ORDER BY players DESC` ? Sorting in a database is *much* better than sorting in PHP.

Comment: can you please post your query? that way i can see if there is an error in it =)

Comment: We can't use the ORDER BY i post another example.. If we do that it will sort acordingly the Turn like `2 1 0` it will not sort the thing like `2 0 1` which is we need.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php to retain your index association.

Answer (score 0):

yeah. perform the sort in query itself with ORDER BY DESC .. it makes life easier..

Comment: Yes i already think that in a first place also. Order By is really easy to sort everything. But it will not sort something like this `2 0 1` and ` 1 2 0` thus, if we use ORDER BY DESC `2 1 0` and ASC `0 1 2` i hope its clear now...